# Is it possible to break a loop using a method in java?

Tags: java, while-loop, break

Example:

```
while(true){

    //some code

    MyMethod();

    //other code
}
```

Is there a way in java to `break` the cycle with a method I created (`MyMethod` here)?

Or the one and only way is to make it return something and then use an if with break?

Comment: Actually, you use exception fo that

Comment: This is, if I'm not wrong, the third variation on the same basic question you make on this subject today. I'm starting to think that you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that is you're stuck with your idea for a solution that may not fit the problem.

Comment: @mkuligowski only if something exceptional happens, of course

Comment: Such side effects should be avoided since they can cause some serious headache when there are things going on that you don't expect and then try to find the culprit. If there's an error or anything similar, you should throw an exception.

Comment: Perhaps the potential return value of MyMethod() should be what you're checking against in your while condition.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca well yes that's quite correct, I am trying to see if I can write something different than `if(a==b)break;` 10 times in my code because without other options that's what I will have to do

Comment: @wattbatt I think it would be more helpful *for you* to try to reduce your problem to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and use that to ask a question. This will have two advantages: 1) it will clear your own ideas on what you're doing 2) it will help people to give you a solution to your actual issue instead of an abstract problem. Because, as it stands, all the answers you received until know *were* correct for the general problem you asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [break statement](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp).

```java
while (true) {
  MyMethod();
  if( somecondition ) { // If the condition is true, then you will exit the loop
    break;
  }
}
```

However, this works but it might be dangerous to use a while loop with a true condition, as you could easily fall in an infinite loop and not be able to exit it.

Your method could also return a boolean value that tells you when to stop. In this case, you could use the following syntax :

```java
while (true) {
  if( MyMethod() )
    break;
}
```

Comment: Or just `while(!MyMethod()) { …}`

Comment: That's even shorter yes 